# What is the running Time complexity of this algorithm that getting all submultiples of n?

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def get_submultiples(n):
    # Get all submultiples of n
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    i = 2
    submultiples = set([1,n])
    m = n
    while i < m:
        if n % i != 0:
            m = int(n/i)+1
        else:
            submultiples.add(i)
            submultiples.add(int(n/i))
        i += 1
    return submultiples
```

1. this algorithm wrote by myself, I want to know what is its O(?). Can anybody help me?
2. it wrote by python and "n" is an integer.

Comment: I am not sure , i think it runs for the o(n) since the loop runs for m values in the worst case

Comment: I don't think so, the m is shrinking in the loop.

Comment: Though it shrink the loop will be running for m value only know

Comment: I had test many n, and it got a correct answer.

Comment: You are right.When it is the worst situation,such like n is prime number, it loops n time.

Comment: Oh, we are wrong, when i use 13 to test it, the loop only run  3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Big-O complexity is complicated by the fact that you conditionally shrink `m`. The more factors `n` has, the less often you shrink `m`. If it has few factors the complexity approaches *O*(√*n*), but if it has many the complexity is closer to *O*(*n*). I don't know exactly how that shakes out for arbitrary values of `n`.

You could improve this by shrinking `m` every iteration, regardless of whether `i` is a factor or not. This would then be equivalent to simply having a fixed upper limit of `√n`, which would give a predictable runtime of *O*(√*n*).

```
def get_submultiples(n):
    submultiples = set()
    for i in range(1, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            submultiples.add(i)
            submultiples.add(n // i)
    return submultiples
```

You could also write it using a generator expression:

```
def get_submultiples(n):
    return set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        (i, n // i)
        for i in range(1, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) + 1)
            if n % i == 0
    ))
```

Or as a generator:

```
def get_submultiples(n):
    for i in range(1, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            yield i
            yield n // i
```

Comment: Oh,yes, O(√n) is the most close answer. I test many n, like 362880, it's equal 2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9 and it has many factors. It takes 601 times for loop, 601*601=361210.